# SMTP class CC readonly is coming when sending email?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

i want to send the Email and using smtp class and i want to Cc also but getting Cc is a read only property.my code below

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MyMailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
MyMailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(this.SenderAddress);
MyMailMessage.CC = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(this.CcAddress);
string m_CcAddress = null;


    public string CcAddress {
        get {
            return this.m_CcAddress;        }
        set {
            this.m_CcAddress = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, cc is a list, not a String.. So you normally would have

```
myMailMessage.cc.Add(m_CcAddress);
```

As demonstrated by [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.cc(v=vs.110).aspx)